# mime64 blob in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a sqlite db that I have to query from my iPhone app.
this database have a blob which contains a list of floats encoded MIME64.

I have to obtain these floats.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//... sqlite statement already defined 

                const void *ptr = sqlite3_column_blob(selectstmt, 18);
                int size = sqlite3_column_bytes(selectstmt, 18);
                data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ptr length:size];
                int idx=0;
                for(;idx<[data length]/sizeof(int);idx+=sizeof(int))


// add to a mutable array or what you need
```

It worked for my need. Hope it can be useful.